# syntax error (comma) in query expression

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

I'm trying to get the user's details from a database to show in some text boxes; however there seems to be a problem with my code. The following error keeps appearing:

> syntax error (comma) in query expression

This is the complete code:

```
string filePath;

try
{
    filePath = (Application.StartupPath + ("\\" + DBFile));
    connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection((ConnectionString + filePath));
    connection.Open();
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader reader;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;

    // ---retrieve user's particulars---
    command.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM Enroll WHERE ID=" + textBox1);
    reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    reader.Read();

    // ---display user's particulars---
    textBox2.Text = reader["SSN"].ToString();
    textBox3.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
    textBox4.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
command.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM Enroll WHERE ID=" + textBox1);
```

so internally .ToString method would have been called on textBox1 and your commandText would have become

```
SELECT * FROM Enroll WHERE ID=System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:
```

Hence the error.

What you probably mean is the text in the textbox

```
command.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM Enroll WHERE ID=" + textBox1.Text);
```

**Note:**
   You should not do it in the first place. You should consider using parameterized queries instead. So, what you should be doing is

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Enroll WHERE ID=@ID");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox1.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: Yeah i literally forgot to add the '.text' and the end of the '+textBox1'

Answer (score 2):

What about changing

```
command.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM Enroll WHERE ID=" + textBox1);
```

to

```
command.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM Enroll WHERE ID=" + textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be more appropriate :

```
command.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM Enroll WHERE ID=" + textBox1.text.toString()+"");
```